# fullcalendar.js timezone difference even without passing any timezone or daylight saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, fullcalendar, momentjs

I've an issue with fullcalendar.js (https://fullcalendar.io/). I create an event in standard ISO format as below:

```
var startDateTime = '2017-07-26T08:00:00';
var endDateTime = '2017-07-26T13:00:00';
var event={id:1 , title: eventData.data('text'), start:startDateTime, end:endDateTime}; 
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);
```

when I try to retrive this date with below code:

```
 var allEvents = [];
 allEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
  var event = $.grep(allEvents, function (v) {     
   alert(moment(+v.start).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
 });
```

I get back a differente value 2017-07-26T10:00:00 instead 2017-07-26T08:00:00 like if the daylight saving has been specified but as you can see i never define a daylight saving nor a timezone

how can i get back the date with the same value as input?

Please, take a look at this jsfiddler for a complete example [fullcalendar example](https://jsfiddle.net/7hnn5k3d/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.[Moment Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

Use moment.utc() to use UTC time.

```
function showEventData(){
 alert('test');
 var allEvents = [];
   allEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
   var event = $.grep(allEvents, function (v) {
     alert(moment.utc(+v.start).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
   });   
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hnn5k3d/2/)